# Rodent proofing a ventilation opening

Tags: basement, ventilation

The 1917 craftsman home (East Bay, California) that I'm closing on has a large 20"x16" opening in the basement/crawl space wall to the outside.

Right now it has chicken wire over it but it's been pushed in and there's rodent debris near by. What's the best way to secure it against rodents? Is 24 gauge 1/4" expanded steel mesh sufficient?

I don't need the opening for access t the crawl space so I could also close it.

Comment: Why not brick it over if you don't need it? Once and for all...

Comment: That may be the only access to the crawlspace.

Comment: It isn't the only access as I have a basement garage (a California thing). My only objection to bricking it up is that it seems like a lot of effort (have to find bricks, get mortar, and build up a brick wall to about 4 feet).  If there's a good solid mesh that'd prevent rodents, that'd be great.

Comment: Add photos? We can make some attractive suggestions. Do you want to use wire? Rodents, of a good size can chew through that wire easily. They can chew through many things. Brick suggestion is good. Or build awooden access door, put latches on it.

Comment: Rodents cannot chew through steel mesh "hardware cloth". It comes in at least two mesh sizes and I would use the smaller one (about 1/4 inch mesh). You could cover this on the inside with fine screen which will keep out small insects. This opening may be important to keep the crawl space ventilated and dry.